# Date field format changes when set to view only

Tags: custom-fields, joomla, date-preferences

I made a custom field. The field type is a Date field. I set the date format to european (Dutch) settings: dd-mm-yyyy, with time = none.
I use the field in a profile that is published as a profile create form, where it works all right.
To allow a contact to view the data they sent trough this profile, I made a profile edit form as a menu item. After logging in, the contact can see this date field, but as view only.
In this last form the view only field presents the data as mm/dd/yyyy.

I checked all the places where date formats are set, changed everything everywhere to dd-mm-yyyy. This does not change the date-format in the view only field.

Is this normal behaviour, a bug or me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug, it should take the settings for the date/time, sounds like it does not.

Comment: If so, how can I signal it as such?

Comment: You can check if it is already reported as a bug on https://issues.civicrm.org and add it if it is not.

Comment: Okay, could not find a bug report about this, so I added a report.